# finding an xpath with many //tr without giving the exact //tr[value]

Tags: xpath

so my issue is I am trying to verify for example "11305487/10" is displaying without giving the tr cell value in the event for some reason it happens to change at some point. I want it to skim the tr looking for the text() I provide but cant seem to get it down. any help is appreciated!

firepath gives me an xpath of

```
html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]
```

the below xpath fails

```
"//table[contains(div[1]/tr/td[4]/text(),'11618632')]"



    <div id="scrollableDocumentsTable" onscroll="onScrollHideFilters();">
    <table id="documentsTable" width="960" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <tbody>
    <tr bgcolor="#008677">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<td align="center">
<td class="BlackSmall" align="left" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">09/25/14</td>
<td class="BlackSmall" align="left" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">10/25/14</td>
<td class="BlackSmall" align="left" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">11618632</td>
<td class="BlackSmall" align="right" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">71.54</td>
<input id="bp_2" type="hidden" value="N" name="bp_2"/>
<td class="BlackSmall" align="left" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">Mail</td>
<td class="BlackSmall" align="right" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">0.00</td>
<td class="BlackSmall" align="left" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">xxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
    <tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`//` to recursively search all sub-nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

```
"//table//td[contains(text(), '11618632')]"
```

`//table` matches all `table` nodes in the document. `//table//td` matches all `td` nodes which are descendants of a `table` node.

`td[contains(text(), '11618632')]` will match only those `td` nodes whose text contains the string `'11618632'`.